# UseEffect API Request not displaying on page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Apologies in advance if similar questions like this have already been answered. I have tried everything, but still cannot figure out why I am experiencing this small bug.
I want this collection of tweets from my Firestore to render on the page when it loads. Right now, it only happens after I make a post request.

This is my request

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const getTweets = async () => {
    const tweets = await firestore.collection('tweet').get();
    tweets.forEach(doc => {
    results.push(doc.data());
    })
  }
  getTweets()
}, [])
```

This is where I'm mapping it to the page:

```js
return (
    <>
      <main className="tweet-container">
        <div className="tweet-container--content">
          {results.map((tweet, index) => (
            <InputResults
            key={index}
            tweet={tweet}
            />
            ))}
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

function App() {
  
    const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {   
      const getTweets = async () => {
        const tweetsData = [];
        const tweets = await firestore.collection('tweet').get();
        tweets.forEach(doc => {
          tweetsData.push(doc.data());
        })
        setResults(tweetsData);
      }
      getTweets()
    }, [])

    return (
      <>
        <main className="tweet-container">
          <div className="tweet-container--content">
            {results.map((tweet, index) => (
                 <h1>{tweet}</h1>
              ))}
          </div>
        </main>
      </>
    )
}
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0):

Always add a **key property** to the elements when used a map function to show them on UI .
As it would help react to differentiate between the elements .

```
return (
      <>
        <main className="tweet-container">
          <div className="tweet-container--content">
            {results.map((tweet, index) => (
                 <h1 key={index}  >{tweet}</h1>
              ))}
          </div>
        </main>
      </>
    )
```